# Parse JSON output for particular key fields

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON content in a file.json.

I need only a particular key field from all this overwhelming information.

Let us assume that I need `web_url`,

The problem here is there are multiple key field with "web_url".

How do only get the `web_url` field I am after?

```
[{"id":196,"iid":1,"project_id":233,"title":"DEV to Master","description":"","state":"merged","created_at":"2019-12-04T14:14:35.424-06:00","updated_at":"2019-12-04T14:14:47.310-06:00","merged_by":{"id":122,"name":"Sengoku","username":"sengk","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/7cvffgfgfgfgf9eb1348d0ba7795a076?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"https://gitlaboo.tests.com/sengk"},"merged_at":"2019-12-04T14:14:47.468-06:00","closed_by":null,"closed_at":null,"target_branch":"master","source_branch":"DEV","upvotes":0,"downvotes":0,"author":{"id":122,"name":"Sengoku","username":"sengk","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/7fgdfdgdfgdvfg9eb1348d0ba7795a076?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"https://gitlaboo.tests.com/sengk"},"assignee":{"id":122,"name":"Sengoku","username":"sengk","state":"active","avatar_url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/7afsdfdvdfvfde24f89eb1348d0ba7795a076?s=80\u0026d=identicon","web_url":"https://gitlaboo.tests.com/sengk"},"source_project_id":233,"target_project_id":233,"labels":[],"work_in_progress":false,"milestone":null,"merge_when_pipeline_succeeds":false,"merge_status":"can_be_merged","sha":"6318e51ea8czfdfsdvdfvdfbc02988ba62c71e5774107e","merge_commit_sha":"6dc5vdfvdfgdfg5bf14e97dea949b8584c0c68d6","user_notes_count":0,"discussion_locked":null,"should_remove_source_branch":null,"force_remove_source_branch":false,"web_url":"https://gitlaboo.tests.com/demo/frog/merge_requests/1","time_stats":{"time_estimate":0,"total_time_spent":0,"human_time_estimate":null,"human_total_time_spent":null},"squash":false}]
```

Comment: Post a complete JSON that is without errors. The one you have isn't syntactically valid. Copy paste your JSON in jsonlint.com and check it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 `web_url` in your JSON.

Can check the below results,

```
.[] | .web_url
.[] | .merged_by.web_url
.[] | .author.web_url
.[] | .assignee.web_url
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is essentially how to find the needle in the haystack, the answer is: use `paths`; more specifically, in your case:

```
jq -c 'paths(. == "https://gitlaboo.tests.com/demo/frog/merge_requests/1")
             | select(.[-1] == "web_url")
' file.json
```

The output gives the path as a JSON array:

```
[0,"web_url"]
```

This can be used directly in jq (using `getpath/1`), or as the basis for a direct query:

```
.[0].web_url
```